# how to add change event on two different UIpickerView in same storyBoard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

i have two different UIpickerView's in same storyboard, and i want to add change event on them and bind different actions with them.

i used below code, it adds event to both the UIpickerView but i want to add to different actions on both of them. But in this case, as both are triggering same action thats why doing the same work.

```
- (void)pickerView:_picker didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{

}
```

Comment: you mean in "`didFinishpic.......`" method? Add some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `tag` to each `UIPickerView` in storyboard, and now in selection method

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
if(pickerView.tag == 0) {

} else if (pickerView.tag == 1) {

}
}
```

based on the `tag` you differentiate the which `UIPickerView` is selected.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (pickerView == self.picker1) {
    //do action
}
else if (pickerView == self.picker2) {
    //do action
}
```

Obviously have each picker declared separately (for example: `picker1` & `picker2`) in your `.h` file and then add this to your `didSelect` with the appropriate action for each picker